# Web Socket - Response Header Connection:upgrade, close

Tags: jquery, sockets, jakarta-ee, tomcat, websocket

I'm using Websocket on tomcat 7.0.53

On local (7.0.42) it works fine

once on line (7.0.53) my response header is getting this :

> 1. Upgrade:   websocket
> 2. Transfer-Encoding: chunked
> 3. Sec-WebSocket-Accept:  Yrwlg8QgBvjUMX8hVqUXDqfZuVk=
> 4. Expires:   Wed, 31 Dec 1969 19:00:00 EST
> 5. Date:  Sat, 24 May 2014 16:08:22 GMT
> 6. Content-Type:  text/html;charset=UTF-8
> 7. **Connection:  upgrade, close**
> 8. Cache-Control: private

The Connection:upgrade, close causes the shuting down of the communication

Please, help. i search evry where and found no solution !!!

Comment: Listen for the event so it doesn't close the connection.

Comment: It smell like a proxy is around. Can you try to use a secure websocket connection?

Comment: Another dubious header is `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`. This is unusual (and wrong) for a WebSocket server. @vtortola is probably right. Proxy around, use WSS to keep it from interfering.

Comment: i'm using a secure connection (wss://) and it does the same in others machine too!

Comment: i removed proxy from browser .. but still does the same thing
New header from chrome:
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:Upgrade
Host:mysite.net
Origin:https://mysite.net
Pragma:no-cache
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions:permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits, x-webkit-deflate-frame
Sec-WebSocket-Key:aFniB5f8zZM1FIm/18MLMg==
Sec-WebSocket-Version:13
Upgrade:websocket
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.114 Safari/537.36

handshake: 'Connection' header value is not 'Upgrade': upgrade, close

Comment: @Ohgodwhy ! what do you mean by listen for the event ? can you provide a sample Code how you do that ? All i do is instantiating the Websocket Object like this :

`websock = new WebSocket(wsUri); 
websock.onopen =function (event){}; 
websock.onclose =function (event){}; 
websock.onmessage = function (event){};`

Should i do something else?

Comment: also i can see the subProtocol parameter being null in createWebSocketInbound method !!! 
Is it the probleme? if yes how can i set it ?

Comment: Which WebSocket implementation are you using? As of 7.0.43, Tomcat 7.0.x added support for JSR356.

Comment: the one that uses 
 **org.apache.catalina.websocket.MessageInbound;** & 
 **org.apache.catalina.websocket.WsOutbound;**
 via:**WebSocketServlet**
 Can find any solution with this JSR 356 (don't know how to use it)
 Any Link ??? Also my server runs under linux

Comment: I'm trying to do something very simple. 
Trying to run the **WebSocket on the tomcat examples Application**.
And i receive the same response that i get when running my own APP.
I made sure all all proxies are closed (did find any!) 
And still cannot find the problem!
The connection is opened and closed immediatelly

here is the Response Header :

Upgrade: **websocket**
Transfer-Encoding: **chunked**
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: EWWfUrXm32lB8qmRO9eSRlDNDmE=
Date: Sun, 08 Jun 2014 08:30:56 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
**Connection**: **upgrade, close**

Comment: I saw smowhere it maybe the **SSL connector** that does that !!! cause even the **example include in the tomcat** distribution does not work !!!